# proxyconnect tcp: x509: certificate is valid for Sachith, not myregistry

Tags: docker, x509certificate, docker-registry

I had followed given steps [here](https://docs.docker.com/registry/recipes/nginx/) to create "Authenticate proxy with nginx".

Certificates were created using `openssh`

```
openssl req  -newkey rsa:4096 -nodes -sha256 -keyout myregistry.key -x509 -days 365 -out myregistry.crt
```

Then `docker-compose up --build` bring docker registry starts.

When I try to push image to registry (from same PC running docker-registry):

`docker push myregistry:5043/test` I get following Error :

> Error response from daemon: Get https://myregistry:5043/v2/: proxyconnect tcp: x509: certificate is valid for Sachith, not myregistry

I tried with `insecure-registry` in `daemon.json`. But this does not get solved, also solution discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41289172/x509-certificate-is-valid-for-xyz-net-not-docker-abc-xyz-net) is not clear for me.

Also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55826250/docker-behind-a-proxy-pull-from-azure-container-registry-works-but-from-regist) saying to add certificates to docker config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by following

`mkdir -p /etc/docker/certs.d/myregistry:5043`

`cp myregistry.crt /etc/docker/certs.d/myregistry:5000/ca.crt`

`cp myregistry.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/ca.crt`

`update-ca-certificates`