# Unable to connect to the server: x509: certificate is valid for control-plane, not my_domain.com

Tags: kubernetes, openssl, kubectl, kubeconfig

I am trying to give user access to Kubernetes using [X.509 Client Certificate](https://dev.to/ajitvedpathak/user-authentication-and-authorization-in-kubernets-access-control-in-kubernetes-3ef1)

I am using(subjectAltName= my_domain.com):

```
openssl req -new -newkey rsa:4096 -nodes -keyout Bob.key -out Bob.csr -subj "/C=DK/ST=Frb/L=Cph/O=engineering/CN=Bob" -addext "subjectAltName = DNS:my_domain.com"
```

kube/config:

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: <..Q0FURS0tLS0tCk..>
    server: https://my_domain.com:<port>
  name: bob
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: bob
    user: Bob
  name: bob
current-context: bob
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: Bob
  user:
    client-certificate: /home/cred/Bob.crt
    client-key: /home/cred/Bob.key
```

Error:

```
Unable to connect to the server: x509: certificate is valid for control-plane,... not my_domain.com
```

Do you know how to make this work behind domain, where the local k8s server ip address is mapped?

Comment: Try the solutions provided in similar stack posts - [Solution 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46360361) and [Solution 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64572987).

Comment: Totally right, I found out the hard way :-)

Comment: Alright, can you confirm what exactly worked for you? so as to add as community answer for the help of other  community members facing same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by Anant Swaraj, the solution is here [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46360361/invalid-x509-certificate-for-kubernetes-master) You need to add `subjectAltName` to the `kubeadm-config` and restart `kube-apiserver`